# unicode combining enclosing circle with natural character

Tags: unicode

I am trying to find a way of combining a natural character such as 'a', or 'ض' with a circle.  I have found combining characters, also combining marks for symbols, which don't apply since symbols don't cover the natural written characters, also enclosed numerics and various other objects, but nothing I have found so far quite satisfies the need to encircle a glyph.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you're going to get is U+20DD COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE, e.g. a⃝. It won't fit all glyphs, but that's just the way it is.

Comment: How would you represent that in C/C++ to achieve the combination?

Comment: UTF8 sequence for U+20DD is E2 83 9D (`"\xe2\x83\x9d"`). It's a combining character, so apply it as a suffix to the character to be encircled.

Comment: Confirmed: `"ℹ\u20DD" === "ℹ⃝"` (`(i)`, if your font doesn't render the ring-circumscribed info glyph.)